# Cómo posicionar una capa div en la parte superior de una pagina Maestra Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, aplicación-web

Tengo una pagina Maestra y en ella necesito posicionar una div  en la parte superior, escribí un código donde lo hace pero cuando agrego elementos a la paginas enlazadas a esta Master entonces esta capa aparece en la parte inferior

Mi Código en Pagina Master

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server"> 
      <div style="top:0px; left:40%; right:40%; width: 55%; height:15%; margin: 0 auto;"> 
       <div style="float:left;"> 
        <input type="submit" ID="btnInicio" value="INICIO" onclick="RedirectPage('../View/otherpage.aspx')" class="btnEncabexadoMaster" />
       </div>
          <div style="float:left;">
        <input type="submit" ID="btnEmpresa"  value="EMPRESAS" onclick="RedirectPage('../View/otherpage.aspx')"  class="btnEncabexadoMaster"  />
              </div>
          <div style="float:left;">
        <input type="submit" ID="btnServicio" value="SERVICIO"  onclick="RedirectPage('../View/otherpage.aspx')"  class="btnEncabexadoMaster" />
              </div>
          <div style="float:left;">
        <input type="submit" ID="btnValorar" value="VALORAR UN SERVICIO" onclick="RedirectPage('../View/otherpage.aspx')"class="btnEncabexadoMaster"  />
              </div>
          <div style="float:left;">
        <input type="submit" ID="btnContacto" value="CONTACTO" onclick="RedirectPage('../View/otherpage.aspx')" class="btnEncabexadoMaster"  />
              </div>
         <div style="float:right">
        <input type="submit" ID="btnRegistro" value="Registro" onclick="RedirectPage('../View/otherpage.aspx')" class="btnEncabexadoMaster2" />
        </div>
         <div style="float:right;""> 
        <input type="submit" ID="btnIniSesion" value="Inicio Sesion" onclick="RedirectPage('../View/otherpage.aspx')" class="btnEncabexadoMaster2"  />
        </div>
     </div>
```

Debería verse siempre así...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saca el html de `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">` y elimina el **ContentPlaceHolder**.

En las páginas enlazadas agrega todo el html dentro de `<asp:Content ID="ContentBody" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">`

Answer (score 2):

En vez de utilizar Divs te aconsejo utilizar un ul, y en vez de botones enlaces.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="../View/otherpage.aspx">INICIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="../View/otherpage.aspx">EMPRESAS</a></li>
    <li><a href="../View/otherpage.aspx">SERVICIO</a></li>
</ul>
<style>
    .menu {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .menu > li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        background: #333;
        height: 30px;
    }

    .menu > li:hover {
        background: #444;
    }

    .menu a {
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]